# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKIX KeyManagerFactory not available

Tags: java, security, ssl

The following code:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
```

Throws exception: `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKIX KeyManagerFactory not available`
on windows 7. The same code works fine on Linux (Linux Mint 14)

JDK version on Windows 7: jdk-1.7.0-u40.

JDK version on Linux: openjdk-1.7.0.(Icetea)

The java.security file on my windows has following security providers.

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun

security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign

security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC

security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider

security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE

security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider

security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider

security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI

security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC

security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

Which security provider is needed for `"PKIX"` and how to enable it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had this same problem myself, which I solved by switching to BouncyCastle. You can include BouncyCastle with your deployment, so you never have to worry about a particular computer lacking the algorithm you need.

Comment: Hi i am using bouncy castle at the start of program.                   Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: Just wondering, what's the value of `KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()` (if you prints this out from your application)?

Comment: @Bruno It's 'SunX509'.

Comment: This makes sense, this it's the default value in the specs. PKIX matters more for the trustmanager, but I'm not sure `PKIX` adds anything to `SunX509` for the keymanager. I'd try `SunX509` just in case.

Comment: Hi Friends Issue is resolved ,I was adding jdk 7 in build path i.e it resolve compile time.but runtime jre was 6.so kindly select you runtime jre as 7 in run configuration . Thanks for all you comments and support.